# How to retreive latest Non-Null from each Column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to extract latest price for products stored in Pandas DataFrame. Sample data can be generated using code below:

```
data = {'PDate':['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04'],
        'Date':['2020-01-04', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-04','2020-01-04'],
        'A':[10,20,30,np.nan],
        'B':[80,90,100,110]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index('PDate', inplace=True)
```

In dataframe created `PDate` is price date and `Date` is the one for which extraction is taking place. Consider `A` and `B` as products, we can see that for product `A` we do not have any price so we should use price for `2020-01-03` where price is `30`. But for product `B` we do have price on `2020-01-04` so we can use that. I want a pandas data frame containing `PDate` most recent avaliable one along with `Date` along with prices for each product.

Desired Output:

```
+---------+------------+------------+-------+
| Product |    Date    |   Pdate    | Price |
+---------+------------+------------+-------+
| A       | 2020-01-04 | 2020-01-03 |    30 |
| B       | 2020-01-04 | 2020-01-04 |   110 |
+---------+------------+------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just do `melt` , then `drop` and `drop_duplicates`

```
out = df.reset_index().melt(['PDate','Date']).dropna().drop_duplicates('variable',keep='last')
        PDate        Date variable  value
2  2020-01-03  2020-01-04        A   30.0
7  2020-01-04  2020-01-04        B  110.0
```